# Can the PCs get hold of the "Piwafwi" or "Piwafwi of Fire Resistance" magic items in the Out of the Abyss adventure?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, published-adventures, out-of-the-abyss

In *Out of the Abyss*, Appendix B: Magic Items, two magic items are listed (p. 222); the [Piwafwi](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/piwafwi-cloak-of-elvenkind) (which is basically just a drow-made Cloak of Elvenkind) and the [Piwafwi of Fire Resistance](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/piwafwi-of-fire-resistance) (the same but with fire resistance while attuned).

However, I cannot find these items anywhere in the adventure available for the characters to take for themselves. On p. 149, there is an NPC who has one:

> Khalessa Draga, a high elf disguised as a drow. It says the following:
>
> > - She owns a *hat of disguise*, which she uses to appear as a female drow while in the company of drow, and **she wears a *piwafwi* (see appendix B).**

That is the only reference to a Piwafwi of any kind being present in the adventure. So unless the party wants to mug this NPC (or if they die and the party loot the body), there are no piwafwi available for the PCs.

Am I missing something, or are there really no Piwafwi (besides the one belonging to that NPC) or Piwafwi of Fire Resistance available throughout that adventure?

Comment: While I can't speak for this adventure, I've noticed similar things in other adventures where there are magic items listed that won't show up except for in the hands of friendly NPCs, or even don't show up altogether, so it's not just a thing that happens in Out of the Abyss.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are more Piwafwi to be found in this adventure:

> Chapter 12: The Tower of Vengeance. Section "What Vizeran Offers" (pages 163-164):
>
> > - Vizeran offers each character a drow *piwafwi* (see appendix B)

However, having DMed this I don't remember the Piwafwi of Fire Resistance ever making an appearance.

Comment: It's been a while since I've run this, and I also don't remember it appearing anywhere either. As I'm preparing to run it again for a new group, I spotted these  items and wondered if it really was nowhere to be found, or if I just overlooked it the first time I ran it. I forgot about Vizeran's gifts, though; good catch (I do remember now giving those out to the players at the time when I ran it before...).

Comment: D&D Beyond is also a valuable resource; [using the site search](https://www.dndbeyond.com/search?q=piwafwi%20of%20fire%20resistance&f=actions,compendium,conditions,skills,rules,weapon-property&c=compendium), I don't see any mention of the *piwafwi of fire resistance* in any compendium content outside the OOTA appendix. I've confirmed there's no mention of the phrase "fire resistance" in any of the chapters using Ctrl+F as well. As for the word "piwafwi" (what a mouthful), the only mentions are those quoted in the question and answer.

Comment: Also, welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Great first answer!